# Clone from BitBucket using SSH fails with "Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

Created a *new*, *empty* repository via bitbucket.org, and configured an access key for read only access, as described [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/add-access-keys/).

However, when trying to clone the repository, this is what I see:

```sh
~/Documents $ git clone git@bitbucket.org:myname/myrepo.git
...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I just created the repository, so it does exist. I'm also fairly certain my SSH setup is correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this was caused by the fact that the repository did not contain any files yet.

After committing a readme file via bitbucket.org, the `clone` command succeeded.